# Converting nvarchar to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a column in SQL where in the data is stored as 102915, 060315 and so on.
The data type of the column is `nvarchar(50)`. I want to convert the above data to a date format.

It should look like 10-29-15 or 10/29/15.

How can I convert the above in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tried quite a few things: One of them is

```
create view v1 
as
    Select 
        CAST([ISSUE] as date) as ISSUE,
        CAST([EXPIRE] as date) as EXPIRE
    from tablename
```

The view is being created.

Note: ISSUE and EXPIRE are the column names which have values like 100515, 060315 and I need to convert all the values in those columns to 10-05-15 or 10/05/15.

When I do a `select * from v1;` I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string.

Comment: What you tried is not working ?

Comment: I tried using cast and convert but didn't help me out.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your attempts so that someone could point out the error...

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and describe what "didn't help me out" looks like, please.

Comment: I am getting an error stating Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: you didn't mention the goal (no, 'i want to format the date' is not your actual goal) so my advice is convert to proper datatype. if the information is a date convert it to date and let the presentation layer to define the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(50) = '102915'

SELECT   CAST(  CAST( '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                      SUBSTRING( @date,5,2)+ --year
                      SUBSTRING( @date,1,2)+ --month
                      SUBSTRING( @date,3,2)  --day
                 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
          AS DATE)
```

result:

[image]

But this will assume your dates are all greater than 1999.

as your date format is MMddYY it's hard to attain the correct date part for the year.

So for your view you can use:

```
create view v1 as
    Select CAST(  CAST( '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],5,2)+ --year
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],1,2)+ --month
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],3,2)  --day
                     AS VARCHAR(10)) 
              AS DATE) as ISSUE
          , 
        CAST(  CAST( '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                          SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],5,2)+ --year
                          SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],1,2)+ --month
                          SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],3,2)  --day
                     AS VARCHAR(10)) 
              AS DATE)  as EXPIRE
    from tablename
```

To have the date in the format mm-dd-yyyy you need to use CONVERT you can see the different conversions [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/):

```
create view v1 as
        Select convert(VARCHAR ,CAST( CAST( '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                              SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],5,2)+ --year
                              SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],1,2)+ --month
                              SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],3,2)  --day
                         AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                   AS DATE), 110) as ISSUE
              , 
            convert(VARCHAR ,CAST(  CAST( '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                              SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],5,2)+ --year
                              SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],1,2)+ --month
                              SUBSTRING( [EXPIRE],3,2)  --day
                         AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                   AS DATE), 110)  as EXPIRE
        from tablename
```

Comment: Almost there. when I try to get it to MM-DD-YYYY I get the same error as earlier.

Comment: CAST(  CAST( 
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],1,2)+ --month
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],3,2)+  --day 
                          '20'+                  --prefix for the year 2000
                          SUBSTRING( [ISSUE],5,2) --year
                     AS VARCHAR(10)) 
              AS DATE) as ISSUE

It's the same one that you provided but just changed the order only to realize that the format of the date datatype doesn't accept that!!!

Comment: Ah I see what you are doing. You wont be able to do it that way. what you need to do is use Convert. I will update my answer to show you how to do that. You can thank me by upvoting ;)

Comment: @akshaybhat ok I've added the different format solution now.

Comment: Still doesn't give the output in MM-DD-YYYY. I even tried using the code 101 instead of 110, but didn't work out!!

Comment: @akshaybhat I've just edited the code. So what you need to do is first cast it to date then convert to VARCHAR with the conversion format 110

Comment: Ahh..there it is!! Worked. Bad day for me, can't get the silly but important things right. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem @akshaybhat, but you have to keep in mind the final result of your view is no longer of the datatype Date. It is now a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using SQL Server 2012, you've got the DATEFROMPARTS function. It takes three int parameters - Year, Month and Day - and returns a date.

With SQL Server 2008 you need to do something more like this -

```
Declare @Year as int=2012
Declare @Month as int=12
Declare @Day as int=31

Select Convert(Date,Convert(varchar(4), @Year)
+
Convert(varchar(2), @Month)
+
Convert(varchar(2), @Day))
```

(http://raresql.com/tag/sql-server-2012-date-and-time-function-datefromparts/)

You can split your input using SUBSTRING, so something like

```
DECLARE @Year nvarchar(4) ='20' + SUBSTRING(InputField,1,2)
```

Etc. Combine the two techniques and you'll have a working solution.

(As an aside though - please don't store dates in the format of your existing column, it's storing up confusion for the future. Use a proper data type and it'll work much better.)

Comment: I am importing the date from a mainframe onto a sql server and hence it is  coming in the aforementioned format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot simpler:

```
select convert(nvarchar(50), convert(date, RIGHT('102915',2) + LEFT('102915',4), 112), 110)
```

and respectively:

```
create view v1 as
    Select 
        convert(nvarchar(50), convert(date, RIGHT([ISSUE],2) + LEFT([ISSUE],4), 112), 110) as ISSUE,
        convert(nvarchar(50), convert(date, RIGHT([EXPIRE],2) + LEFT([EXPIRE],4), 112), 110) as EXPIRE
    from tablename
```

Comment: Well, you asked for date conversion. I edited to output the date as a string in the desired format.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this:

```
CONVERT(date, YOUR_DATE_FIELD, 1) AS DATE
```

Sometimes, you can't convert as easy as above and you need to use functions like LEFT, SUBSTR AND RIGHT.

Something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(field, 2) + SUBSTR(field, 2, 2) + RIGHT(field, 2), 1) AS DATE
```

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx